# Need Help in ASP.Net C# login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, visual-studio-2013, login-control

What is wrong with this code? I have tried a lot of methods. But it always show login failed. No Build Errors though. I have a database named honeypot and a table called register in it,with username row and password row as varchars. I'm using built in login control. Can anyone help? I'm using Visual studio 2013.

**home.aspx.cs**

```
enter code here
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CodeInjection4
{
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        }
    }

    private static int count = 0;

    protected void log1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (log1.UserName == "Admin" && log1.Password == "Admin")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Adminhome.aspx");
        }
        else if (YourValidationFunction(log1.UserName, log1.Password))
        {
            Session["User"] = log1.UserName;
            e.Authenticated = true;
            Response.Redirect("userhome.aspx");
            log1.TitleText = "Successfully Logged In";
        }
        else
        {
            e.Authenticated = false;
            count++;
            if (count >= 3)
            {
                count = 0;
                Session["User"] = log1.UserName;
                Server.Transfer("MainPage.aspx");
            }
        }
    }

    private SqlConnection strConnection = new
        SqlConnection("server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;database=honeypot;integrated security=true;");

    private bool YourValidationFunction(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        bool boolReturnValue = false;
        String SQLQuery = "SELECT UserName, Password FROM Register";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQLQuery, strConnection);
        SqlDataReader Dr;
        try
        {
            strConnection.Open();
            Dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (Dr.Read())
            {
                if ((UserName == Dr["UserName"].ToString()) & (Password == Dr["Password"].ToString()))
                {
                    boolReturnValue = true;
                }
            }
            Dr.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return boolReturnValue;
    }

    protected void lnkRegis_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("AdUserAcc.aspx");
    }
}
}
```

**Home.aspx**

```
enter code here

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="CodeInjection4.Home" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script runat="server">
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #form1 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .auto-style1 {
        width: 981px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .auto-style2 {
        width: 961px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    Forestalling Code Injection</div>
    <asp:Login ID="log1" OnAuthenticate="log1_Authenticate" runat="server" Width="1062px">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="2">Log In</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" class="auto-style2">
                                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="auto-style1">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="log1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" class="auto-style2">
                                    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="auto-style1">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="log1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="Remember me next time." />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                    <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
                                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="log1" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Register" PostBackUrl="~/AdUserAcc.aspx" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Turn on your debugger, set a break point, and step through your code until it fails. Examine all your variables on each step until you figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Also, are you storing passwords as plain-text in the DB? If the passwords are hashed then comparing that value to what the user enters will not work.

Comment: Im storing passwords as plain text, also no errors are reported, it just shows login failed in the page itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting all the users and looping through them. You have break out of the loop if you find a matching username and password such as

```
if ((UserName == Dr["UserName"].ToString()) & (Password == Dr["Password"].ToString()))
{
    boolReturnValue = true;
    break;
}
```

Othwerwise the next user will set it back to false.

A couple of notes:

1. Selecting all users and iterating through them is not scalable and wouldn't perform well. Instead you can pass in the username and password in WHERE clause. If you get a match then the login info is correct.
2. I'd recommend using logical-AND operator (&&) instead of bitwise-AND (&). Here's a SO thread with related discussion: [Usage & versus &&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537607/usage-versus)
3. Consider using salted password hashes as opposed to plaintext passwords.

Comment: As a 4th point, I would recommend not directly plugging in input strings in a query, since that exposes you to sql injection, instead use [SqlCommand Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) for example

Comment: I thought you said it was working? Are you able to debug it? Just place a breakpoint at the beginning of YourValidationFunction and step through.

Comment: I had to edit the connection string too. Thats y it showed error after adding your correction. Sorry