# Multiple criteria for LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2014

I am trying to create a LINQ query that will filter out data with criteria from two different columns.

I am trying to get data between two dates from `Time_Data_1` column only when a specific string value is met from `Section_Data` column,
ie,
Between `2016/5/15` and `2016/6/16` when `SelectedOption = Something` 
This is what I have, which is not working.

```
 DataGridOne.DataContext = sql.Time_TBLs.Where(item =>
                item.Time_Data_1 < new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month - 1, 15) &&
                item.Time_Data_1 > new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 16) &&
                item.Section_Data == SelectedOption);
```

This query below works for the single criteria of getting data between two dates. But it picks up every bit of data between those dates.

```
Column1.DataContext = sql.Time_TBLs.Where(item =>
                    item.Time_Data_1 < new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month - 1, 15) &&
                    item.Time_Data_1 > new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 16)
```

How do add a second criteria to the query?

EDIT: Typo, supposed to && when I put &

Comment: *"This is what I have, which is not working"*. 'Not working' is never enough description of a problem. In what way the query is not working? What did it return that you don't want?

Comment: @har07, that is it, it returns nothing. ie, not working

Comment: You want to filter between two dates i.e between `2016/05/15` and `2016/06/16` but your condition says you want less then `2016/05/15` and greater than `2016/06/16`. `DataGridOne.DataContext = sql.Time_TBLs.Where(item =>
                item.Time_Data_1 > new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month - 1, 15) &&
                item.Time_Data_1 < new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 16) &&
                item.Section_Data == SelectedOption);` Try this It will work.

Comment: @FanjoLama. Thanks, that sorted me out. Sometimes the simplest things can allude you. I was concentrating on syntax so much I just did not see that. Thanks

Comment: @KyloRen your welcome. I will post this. Will you mark this answer.

Comment: @FanjoLama, Done. Thanks again.

Comment: @KyloRen Thanks. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional statement is wrong. 
You want to filter between two dates i.e between `2016/05/15` and `2016/06/16` but your condition says you want less then `2016/05/15` and greater than `2016/06/16`.

Your code should be like this.

```
DataGridOne.DataContext = sql.Time_TBLs.Where(item =>
item.Time_Data_1 > new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month - 1, 15)
&& item.Time_Data_1 < new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 16) 
&& item.Section_Data == SelectedOption);
```

Answer (score 1):

Any specific error/issue you are getting?

As far as code goes all I would say is possibly BODMAS and bitwise & operator.
Read more on & on
[Usage & versus &&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537607/usage-versus)

Meanwhile does this code work for you?

```
DataGridOne.DataContext = sql.Time_TBLs.Where(item =>
(item.Time_Data_1 < new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month - 1, 15) &&
item.Time_Data_1 > new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 16)) &&
item.Section_Data == SelectedOption);
```

PS : When working with pure DateTime, i find it easier to do 17 instead of 16 for dates. As all times default to 00:00:0000, and hence if you have data like 16/06/2016 07:05:0000 it would not be fetched back from the query that checks for DateTime.Day of 16.

Comment: No, that is not working, I must have clipped off the extra `&` it was supposed to be `&&`

Comment: Please check the post script note. Else post the example data. as far as code goes, it doesn't look wrong.

Comment: No data is returned, so there is nothing to work from

Comment: Thanks, I have it working now. I had the dates screwed. UV for the help.