# I want to understand AND (&&) run time exception

Tags: c#, exception, compiler-errors, nullreferenceexception

Hello everyone today I was working to make API.I got confused when I saw different behavior of C# compiler. let me explain:

I get exception:

```
If(userLoginModel.UserId>0)
{
//do something
}
else{
//do something
}
```

**Exception: {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}**

Yes it is null;
But if write :

```
if (userLoginReturnModel != null && userLoginReturnModel.UserId >0)
{
//do something
}
else
{
//do something
}
```

**This code did not throw any Exception.**

**Note: My question is why compiler is not throwing any exception on 2nd code because there is && condition in if so when compiler will check that userLoginReturnModel.userId > 0 then this will also need to throw exception because object is null. And as we know that both condition will be check in if. Any answer with good explanation.**

Comment: If I ask you to retrieve my book from the bookcase, but I don't have a bookcase, that's a problem - right? Same thing with null. If you try and access an instance of `userLoginReturnModel` but you don't have one - that's a problem. `&&` short-circuits the if statement so it never executes the second half.

Comment: Please read the question again @John . Thank you

Comment: Why? What did I misunderstand?

Comment: You first comment is not matching.

Comment: @John the question was actually why only the first condition is checked in second example.

Comment: @John, the question is about the behaviour of `&&` and how it *avoids* a `NullReferenceException`, not how to fix one, thus not a possible dupe of that question

Comment: Thank you #John I got my answer from @Piotr Wojsa

Comment: @Wajidkhan if it answers your question you can mark it as correct answer to close this topic.

Comment: To people like Me - John's comment answered the situation well. But may be others need more detailed answer.

Comment: Suggest you edit your question. Your first example references userLoginModel you null check references userLoginReturnModel

Comment: @Wajidkhan: see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case of:

```
if (userLoginReturnModel != null && userLoginReturnModel.UserId >0)
```

if the first condition is false then next is not checked (because there is no need to do so - false && anything gives false).

Similiar with || - if first is true then next are not checked (no need - true || anything gives true).

Comment: Maybe as a appendix: the expection would occur, when only concating the bool confitions with one "&". Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537607/usage-of-versus

Answer (score 2):

in this case if userLoginReturnModel is null you will have:

`if ( false && ...`

do you need to check conditions after false? False && true is still false. so rest of conditions doesn't matter and will not be checked.