# C# I need some simple fix for this warning for will be empty operator

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a simple if and and and condition but it breaks the operator and gives the same result: **Your are a parrot.**
Is there any fix?

```
                if (mouse > dog & mouse > cat & mouse > parrot);
                {
                    this.BackgroundImage = Animal_Personality_Test.Properties.Resources.a;
                }
                if (dog > mouse & dog > cat & dog > parrot) ;
                {
                    this.BackgroundImage = Animal_Personality_Test.Properties.Resources.b;
                }
                if (cat > mouse & cat > dog & cat > parrot) ;
                {
                    this.BackgroundImage = Animal_Personality_Test.Properties.Resources.c;
                }
                if (parrot > mouse & parrot > dog & parrot > cat) ;
                {
                    this.BackgroundImage = Animal_Personality_Test.Properties.Resources.d;
                }
```

I was expecting: **You are a mouse!**

```
                if (mouse > dog & mouse > cat & mouse > parrot);
                {
                    this.BackgroundImage = Animal_Personality_Test.Properties.Resources.a;
                }
                if (dog > mouse & dog > cat & dog > parrot) ;
                {
                    this.BackgroundImage = Animal_Personality_Test.Properties.Resources.b;
                }
                if (cat > mouse & cat > dog & cat > parrot) ;
                {
                    this.BackgroundImage = Animal_Personality_Test.Properties.Resources.c;
                }
                if (parrot > mouse & parrot > dog & parrot > cat) ;
                {
                    this.BackgroundImage = Animal_Personality_Test.Properties.Resources.d;
                }
```

Comment: Maybe you meant `&&` (logical and) instead of `&` (binary and)? Also why did you write `;` after each `if` line? Those should definitely not be there

Comment: @Rafalon please do not misguide people - both `&&` and `&` are logical operators when acting on boolean values. I assume you know the difference in behavior between those too and just decided to mis-name one.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, by the time I realized the names were wrong (apparently it should be conditional vs logical and not logical versus binary), I couldn't edit my comment anymore. Thanks for pointing that out. One can see in the linked question that this naming confusion is quite spread

Answer (score 3):

In C#, writing:

```cs
if (condition) ; // <-- note the ; here
{
  foo();
}
```

is equivalent to:

```cs
if (condition) { /* do nothing */ }
foo(); // <-- do foo() anyway
```

Therefore, your current code will just sequentially replace the background:

```cs
this.BackgroundImage = Animal_Personality_Test.Properties.Resources.a;
this.BackgroundImage = Animal_Personality_Test.Properties.Resources.b;
this.BackgroundImage = Animal_Personality_Test.Properties.Resources.c;
this.BackgroundImage = Animal_Personality_Test.Properties.Resources.d;
```

Which is why you get the last image in the end, regardless your conditions.

You should definitely get rid of those `;` at the end of your `if` lines.

---

As a side note, you should be aware that `&` and `&&` are different things. See [c# - Usage of `&` versus `&&`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537607/usage-of-versus)